HTML page loading with favicon when running in browser directly but not with favicon when running from local server
I have created a simple http server using http module. On receipt of GET request with correct url, first the HTML file is being read and stored in a variable using fs.readFileSync() method and then it is being written to the response body and sent along with the response. But in this case the favicon is not loaded with the page.
Note: I am using Visual Studio Code.
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const server = http.createServer(serverFunc);
server.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server is running at <http://localhost:3000/>"));
function serverFunc(req, res){
    switch(req.method){
        case "GET":
            responseFunc();
            break;
        case "POST":
        case "PUT":
        case "DELETE":
        default:
            res.statusCode = 405;
            res.statusMessage = "Method Not Allowed";
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            res.end("Not Allowed");
            break;
    }
    function responseFunc(){
        if(req.url === "/"){
            res.statusCode = 202;
            res.statusMessage ="OK";
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            res.setHeader("charset", "UTF-8");
            let html = fs.readFileSync("index.html");
            res.write(html);
            res.end();
        }else{
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.statusMessage ="Not Found";
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            res.end("Page Not Found!");
        }
    }
}

Expected page load with favicon but favicon is not loading.

"the favicon is not loaded with the page" - In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, when loading the page, is a request made for favicon.ico?  What is the server's response?  What response was expected?  Why?

under network tab no request for favicon.ico is made by the browser. Rather one error it is showing: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a :3000/icon.ico:1 status of 404 (Not Found).

It sounds like you may have code on your page which indicates that it should look for icon.ico instead of favicon.ico.  If this is unexpected then you should check the code on your page.  Though the response is certainly not unexpected given the code shown in the question.  According to the code shown, if a request is made for / then the response should be the content of the file index.html, and all other requests should result in a 404 response.  Did you just forget to include code to handle other requests?

sorry for the confusion. I have mentioned favicon here to indicate it using common name. But with file name no issue is there. Image file name is icon.ico. All the files are in the same directory. Below is the html code part for linking icon:                                       

As per my understanding, when a html page is loaded, all the other files linked with it like css, image, js files are loaded with it automatically.

A request is made automatically, but the result of that request is whatever the server returns.  If the web server has no knowledge of that file or no way to meaningfully handle that request then it won't respond with the content of the file.

From a comment on the question:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a :3000/icon.ico:1 status of 404 (Not Found)

This is an expected and correct response given the code shown.  In your server code you handle exactly one specific request:
if(req.url === "/"){
    res.statusCode = 202;
    res.statusMessage ="OK";
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    res.setHeader("charset", "UTF-8");
    let html = fs.readFileSync("index.html");
    res.write(html);
    res.end();
}

So if the browser makes a request for / (the root of the server) then the server responds with the content of the file index.html.
All other requests get this response:
res.statusCode = 404;
res.statusMessage ="Not Found";
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
res.end("Page Not Found!");

A request for /icon.ico is part of "all other requests".
It sounds like you just forgot to handle that request.  For example:
else if(req.url === "/icon.ico"){
    res.statusCode = 202;
    res.statusMessage ="OK";
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/x-icon");
    let ico = fs.readFileSync("icon.ico");
    res.write(ico);
    res.end();
}

This is of course assuming the name and location of the file you want the server to return.  If yours is different, adjust for your needs.

implemented it but the issue persists.

@ManasGhosh: What is the updated code?  In your browser’s debugging tools, what is the request being made?  Has the response changed at all?

code updated as per your comment to handle the request for ico file as well. in debugging tool, the 404 error for ico is not showing anymore. neither any other error. but the icon is still not loading. is there any vs code settings i need to change? i have not created any separate project. just put the html, js, ico files in the same directory. using windows 10.

@ManasGhosh: "the 404 error for ico is not showing anymore" - In your browser's debugging tools, when the request is made for icon.ico, is the server responding with the correct result?  You can observe the request/response on the Network tab of those tools.

under browser network tab no error is showing but no request is made for icon.ico file as well. checked with console.log, part written for icon.ico request is not at all running in this process.

@ManasGhosh: Have you cleared your browser cache in any way?  Perhaps a Ctrl-F5 refresh of the page to force resources to be re-loaded?  If the page itself is no longer even requesting the file then that suggests something has changed in the HTML, which isn't included or referenced in the question above and may be a separate problem.  Alternatively, if the browser has previously requested and cached a response for this file then it may not be requesting it again and needs a forced refresh.  You can also manually request the file by putting its URL directly in the browser.

neither js nor html has been changed. did manual refresh but still icon is not loading. all file names are same both in js & html files so there's no mismatch with names. when loaded the page from ms edge, the code for icon.ico request part is running but still pic is not loading. chrome is not even requesting for that icon.ico.

@ManasGhosh: "when loaded the page from ms edge, the code for icon.ico request part is running but still pic is not loading" - And in that browser's debugging tools, in the network info, what is the actual response from the server?  In any browser, when you make the request manually, what is the actual response from the server?  If you want to test whether the server-side code you've written is returning the correct response, you need to make that request and examine that response.

under network tab neither chrome nor edge is showing any details. but now both browsers are sending the request for icon.ico file and the code to handle that is running. but the icon is not loading. when putting local server address/icon.ico directly in the browser address/url path, the image is loading in browser but not with the html page as icon.
